# Wake on LAN Port Forwarding not Working

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, wake-up

I am trying to configure the server I run from my home with Wake on LAN so that it is not necessary for me to keep it running when I do not need it. I have been able to get it to work on when the packet is sent from my own network, but when I try to send the magic packet to the server from another network via UDP port 9, I am unable to get the machine to wake. Currently, my router lists the port forwarding configuration like so:

[image: WOL Port Forwarding Configuration]

What is the problem? I've used Wake on LAN with the machine for some time on my network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual answer to this question is that your router's ARP cache entry for your sleeping machine expired. You need to enter a static ARP mapping for your sleeping machine into your router's ARP table. Not all routers make this easy, though, so you may be stuck. Or you may find success with open source router firmware distros like OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.

Comment: When I am trying to wake the machine, the machine is not in a sleep state. It is fully powered off.

Comment: Same answer still applies. If you're able to use magic packets locally to wake (or trigger a boot of) the machine, but not able to use them from a remote network, it's usually that the router forgot what MAC address corresponds to your machine's IP address.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this. Would you mind offering more assistance? - http://superuser.com/q/1089828/