# Add Static ARP Entry to Verizon AC1750 Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, wireless-router

As documented in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1089768/wake-on-lan-port-forwarding-not-working), I need to make a static ARP entry on my router. My router is a [Verizon AC1750](https://www.verizon.com/home/accessories/fios-quantum-gateway/), and I am facing some difficulty along the way. From what I can gather from the router's user interface, I cannot add a static ARP entry from it, however I have read that it is possible to add such an entry by using telnet to log in to the router.

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/206620/how-to-automatically-reboot-your-router-the-geeky-way/) contains the following screenshot showing that telnet can be enabled on a Verizon router.

[image: Enabling Telnet on Verizon Router]

Seeing this, I decided to log in to my router and enable the option, but when I got to the "Local Administration" page on my router, this is what I saw.

[image: Enabling SSH on Verizon Router]

I have no problem with using SSH instead of Telnet, especially since SSH is certainly more secure, but SSH does not seem to be working properly. When I log in to my router via SSH, here is what I see.

[image: Loggin in to Router via SSH]

I have limited experience with SSH, although I have used it a little bit. When this terminal was presented to me, I did what I usually do when I see a console and don't know what to do. I typed `help`, which returned a very unhelpful error: `-sh: help: not found`.

I am now lost and have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

You got to the command line (command interpreter shell) of a stripped down copy of Linux or other Unix-like OS.

Most Unixes have an `arp` command for working with the ARP table. To enter a static ARP mapping for your host, you most likely need to type:

```
arp -s IPAddress MACAddress
```

(Replace `IPAddress` and `MACAddress` with the correct addresses of the machine you want to always be able to wake.)

I believe most Linuxes still have an `arp` command even though it's been deprecated in favor of the `ip` command. If not, look into `ip neighbor add …`

That is, something like this:

```
ip neighbor add 192.168.0.200 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55 dev eth0 nud permanent
```

Note that setting static ARP entries this way is not persistent across reboots of your router. How to make it persistent in your particular router's Unix-like OS is hard to say, but since it's probably a stripped down Linux similar to OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc., you should be able to find suggestions from other forums that may work on your box. Many Unix-like OSes have boot-time startup scripts (known as "run command" or `rc` scripts) in `/etc`. So you may be able to add that `arp -s …` or `ip neighbor add …` command to a file like `/etc/rc.local` to make sure it gets run every time your router boots.

Comment: Neither of these commands are working. When I try the `arp` one, I get the error `-sh: arp: not found`. I tried the command again with an `sh` at the beginning of it, so `sh arp`, and I got the error `sh: can't open 'arp'`. The same thing happened when I tried to use the `ip` command.